# inequality on real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose one is given real numbers  $\alpha_1,  \lambda_0 \ge1$ and $ \lambda_1$ such that   $\alpha_1^2\le1$ and  $\lambda_0^2=1+\lambda_1^2$. Then it is easy to show that $\lambda_0+\alpha_1\lambda_1\ge0$. I am trying to prove this in the general form such that
Given;
$\alpha_1^2+...+ \alpha_n^2\le1$ and $\lambda_0^2=1+\lambda_1^2+...+\lambda_n^2.$ $(\lambda_0\ge1)$
Show that
$\lambda_0+\alpha_1\lambda_1+...+\alpha_n\lambda_n\ge0.$
This seems to be generally simple, so just an indication towards some standard inequality may be sufficient.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$|\alpha_{1}\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda_{n}|\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha_{i}\lambda_{i}|\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha^2_{i}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda^2_{i}}\le\sqrt{\lambda^2_{0}-1}\le |\lambda_{0}|=\lambda_{0}$$
so
$$\lambda_{0}\ge |\alpha_{1}\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda_{n})|\ge -(\alpha_{1}\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda_{n})$$
so
$$\lambda_{0}+\alpha_{1}\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda_{n}\ge 0$$